# Floor panel bulging up

Tags: flooring

recently I noticed a portion of my floor that seems to be bulging. I imagine it might be because the weather has been warming up (Central Texas) causing all of the stress on the floor to gather at this point. Could this be the case? Can I possibly fix this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Bulging floor board]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a water leak somewhere in your wall find it fast. since it has been raining for 2 weeks its most likey rain water from outside. im assuming this is wall is on the side of your house. so the other side of this wall is out side? also how old is house. is it on a concert slab or pier and beam. i think i see the paint pilling on the baseborad so the rot is also in the way more info is needed

Comment: I agree with @joe. Find the leak fast. You probably already have dryrot and maybe mold. Fix the leak, then work on repairing the floorboard. The bulge is not from stress "because the weather has been warming up."  Its from moisture. Is there a sink, toilet or shower above this area?

Comment: Hey, yea it turns out that my sink was leaking and causing the water to flow to the lowest point and flow under the boards causing them to warp. Thanks for the help!!!